# Webview is not showing Html Properlly

Tags: android, android-webview, saxparser

I am new in android development.

Please check this url -

http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml

Please check handout's (Cat_name) cat_desc it is not showing properly in android webview.

I don't know why, can anyone help me or having any idea?

This is my code-

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes 
        attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentTag=localName;
    Log.v("in start elelmet", "in start elelmet");
    if(qName.equals("Table")){
        buffer=new StringBuffer();
        itemTagStarted=true;

        item=new NewsItem();
    }

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if(itemTagStarted){
        if(currentTag.equals("Cat_Name")){
            item.setCatname(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
        }

        if(currentTag.equals("Cat_id")){
            item.setCatid(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
        }

        if(currentTag.equals("Cat_Desc")){
            buffer.append(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {
    currentTag="";
    if(qName.equals("Table")){
        itemTagStarted=false;
        newsList.add(item);
    }

    if(qName.equals("Cat_Desc")){
        item.setCatdesc(buffer.toString());
        Log.v("Description data",buffer.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    Log.v("parsing completed","parsing completed : array size : "+newsList.size());
}

});
}
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My WebView Class-

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

    Intent intent=getIntent();

    String pdf=intent.getStringExtra("str");

   mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

   mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

   mWebView.loadData(pdf,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

}

Thanks & Regards

Arpit Trivedi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(...) to set your Cat_Desc value? I tested your site with a simple SAXParser, dumping the output into loadDataWithBaseURL and got a displayable output in the WebView.

```
WebView mWebView;
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"your_string", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

try this;

Answer (score 3):

Use this method

```
WebView mWebView;

mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"your_string", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```